# PHP Warning: socket_bind(): Host lookup failed [11001]:

Tags: php, sqlite, sockets, web-deployment, web-development-server

I already tried all the possible solution on YouTube, Google on the Host Lookup failed but still I got an error of "PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): Host lookup failed [11001]:"

[image: Error on php-sockets.php]

Here's my code on the PHP socket.

```
 <?php
    define('HOST_NAME',"localhost"); 
    // define('HOST_NAME',"192.168.43.49"); 
    define('PORT',"2306");
    $null = NULL;
    
    class _sHandler {
        function send($message) {
            global $clientSocketArray;
            $messageLength = strlen($message);
            foreach($clientSocketArray as $clientSocket)
            {
                @socket_write($clientSocket,$message,$messageLength);
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        function unseal($socketData) {
            $length = ord($socketData[1]) & 127;
            if($length == 126) {
                $masks = substr($socketData, 4, 4);
                $data = substr($socketData, 8);
            }
            elseif($length == 127) {
                $masks = substr($socketData, 10, 4);
                $data = substr($socketData, 14);
            }
            else {
                $masks = substr($socketData, 2, 4);
                $data = substr($socketData, 6);
            }
            $socketData = "";
            for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
                $socketData .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
            }
            return $socketData;
        }
    
        function seal($socketData) {
            $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
            $length = strlen($socketData);
            
            if($length <= 125)
                $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
            elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
                $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
            elseif($length >= 65536)
                $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
            return $header.$socketData;
        }
    
        function doHandshake($received_header,$client_socket_resource, $host_name, $port) {
            $headers = array();
            $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $received_header);
            foreach($lines as $line)
            {
                $line = chop($line);
                if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
                {
                    $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
                }
            }
    
            $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
            $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
            $buffer  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
            "WebSocket-Origin: $host_name\r\n" .
            "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host_name:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
            "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
            socket_write($client_socket_resource,$buffer,strlen($buffer));
        }
        
        function newConnectionACK($client_ip_address) {
            $message = 'New client ' . $client_ip_address.' joined';
            $messageArray = array('connection_message'=>$message,'connection_message_type'=>'chat-connection-ack');
            $ACK = $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
            return $ACK;
        }
        
        function connectionDisconnectACK($client_ip_address) {
            $message = 'Client ' . $client_ip_address.' disconnected';
            $messageArray = array('message'=>$message,'message_type'=>'chat-connection-ack');
            $ACK = $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
            return $ACK;
        }
        
    }
    $_sHandler = new _sHandler();
    
    $socketResource = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_set_option($socketResource, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
    socket_bind($socketResource, 0, PORT);
    socket_listen($socketResource);
    
    $clientSocketArray = array($socketResource);
    while (true) {
        $newSocketArray = $clientSocketArray;
        socket_select($newSocketArray, $null, $null, 0, 10);
        
        if (in_array($socketResource, $newSocketArray)) {
            $newSocket = socket_accept($socketResource);
            $clientSocketArray[] = $newSocket;
            
            $header = socket_read($newSocket, 1024);
            $_sHandler->doHandshake($header, $newSocket, HOST_NAME, PORT);
            
            socket_getpeername($newSocket, $client_ip_address);
            $connectionACK = $_sHandler->newConnectionACK($client_ip_address);
            
            $_sHandler->send($connectionACK);
            
            $newSocketIndex = array_search($socketResource, $newSocketArray);
            unset($newSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);
        }
        
        foreach ($newSocketArray as $newSocketArrayResource) {  
            while(socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0) >= 1){
                $socketMessage = $_sHandler->unseal($socketData);
                $messageObj = json_decode($socketMessage);
                $_sHandler->send($_sHandler->seal(json_encode($messageObj)));
                break 2;
            }
            
            $socketData = @socket_read($newSocketArrayResource, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
            if ($socketData === false) { 
                socket_getpeername($newSocketArrayResource, $client_ip_address);
                // $connectionACK = $_sHandler->connectionDisconnectACK($client_ip_address);
                $_sHandler->send($connectionACK);
                $newSocketIndex = array_search($newSocketArrayResource, $clientSocketArray);
                unset($clientSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);         
            }
        }
    }
    socket_close($socketResource);
```

from line 94 and 95 I always got an error on this part:

```
$socketResource = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socketResource, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socketResource, 0, PORT);
socket_listen($socketResource);
```

What should I do to fix the socketresource based on the image above.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to follow the proper protocol for the command....

```
socket_bind($socketResource, 0, PORT);
```

the second argument *MUST* be an address....
[PHP.com](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php)

that is why you are getting the message (which tells you the issue - somewhat...) about an 'invalid argument'.

I tried your code and it has some other issues, but your question was about the error on this line, so it seems you are still working on it.

Put the address you want to connect with in there instead of '0' - that should get you going again.